# iOS - Changing auto layout constraint in code not updating view position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, iboutlet

I have a UIViewController designed in Interface Builder (Storyboard) that contains a UISearchBar.  The UISearchBar has an auto layout constraint to pin it to the top layout guide.  In my UIViewController subclass I have an `IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint` connected to the constraint so that I can adjust it in code.  Depending on user events, I hide/unhide the UISearchBar by modifying the constraint's `constant` property between 0 and -44, which also slides up the views which are placed below the UISearchBar.  I have used this technique before and all works well.

My problem is that I am now using 4 instances of this UIViewController within a parent container UIViewController with a UITabBar.  When the UITabBar tab selection is changed, I swap in the appropriate instance using `insertSubView`.  The problem is that the UISearchBar only slides up in one of the tab page instances.  In the other 3 none of the views move.  I have used `NSLog` to monitor the value of the constraint's `constant` property and it is being changed in each instance, just not affecting the view positions.  I'm guessing it's something to do with the IBOutlet only recognising being connected to one instance?

I'm using Xcode 5.1 and my app is targetting iOS7.

**UPDATE**

I've now realised that it's only the first child view controller (tab page) where the repositioning of views doesn't work, the following 3 pages all work.

Comment: Nope, that should not be an issue. Did you call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` after modifying the `constant`?

Comment: Yes, already calling that.

Comment: Make sure that this constraint setting line-of-code was executed in mainthread and also give a try to  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: Yes tried changing edgesForExtendedLayout but had no effect, only using mainthread.